# Cannot change the Y cordinate of the UILabel programmatically

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, uilabel

hi Im programmatically creating an `UILabel` like this

`

```
- (UILabel *)titleLabel {
if (!_titleLabel) {
    _titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _photoView.frame.size.height, _photoView.frame.size.width, 100.0)];
   // _titleLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    _titleLabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    _titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    _titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    [self addSubview:_titleLabel];
}
return _titleLabel;
```

}`

this `_photoView` is an `UIImageView` I have created already. I want to change the `UILabel` View Y value. But the problem is when I change this second parameter label y position is not changing. Any one can tell e the reason for this.

And this is how I created the ImageView

`

```
  - (UIImageView *)photoView {
  if (!_photoView) {
    _photoView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    _photoView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _photoView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _photoView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _photoView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self addSubview:_photoView];
}
return _photoView;
}`
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you disable auto layout in Interface Builder. My SO answer on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042733/programmatically-moving-a-uilabel-in-a-xib-file/21042987#21042987

Comment: I'm not seeing the part where you are changing the `Y` value you mentioned...

Comment: I tryed to change the second parameter of this _titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _photoView.frame.size.height, _photoView.frame.size.width, 100.0)];

Comment: I have use a custom class for a cell and there is no xib for that

Comment: why don't you play with the `center` if you don't want to change the size of the `UILabel`?

Answer (score 0):

In this line , you have used two types init

```
[[[UILabel alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _photoView.frame.size.height, _photoView.frame.size.width, 100.0)]
```

change this line to

```
 [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, _photoView.frame.size.height, _photoView.frame.size.width, 100.0)]
```